# Redirecting index page in wampserver

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wampserver

i create a site in a wampserver by creating a folder that include all site pages and named

the folder  for example xxxx

when i run http://localhost its open the index of the wamp server

what i want is to open the index of xxxx when i run the localhoust without adding xxxx

in the path like http://localhost/xxxx

so is that possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possible solutions here:

1. Reconfigure apache to use xxxx as document root
2. Setup a redirect in your main directory to the subdirectory, i.e. via a `.htaccess` rewrite rule or by sending a redirection `header()` in the root `index.php` file.

Answer (score 4):

in your `httpd.conf` file find `DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"`

and change it to `DocumentRoot "f:/wamp/www/xxxx"`